# sending mouse/keyboard events on remote desktop

Tags: python

So I am trying to set up a Continuous integration environment using Jenkins.

One of the build step requires a series of mouse actions/movements to accomplish a task in Excel. I have already written a python script using the ctypes library to do this.

The script works perfectly fine if I run it either through Jenkins or on the server itself when I am actively logged in to the server using remote desktop connection, but as soon as I minimize/close the connection and then run the script from Jenkins, it seems the mouse events never get executed. Is there something I can add to the script to make this work? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: do you have a display configured and X installed?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not exactly sure what do you mean by that. Can you elaborate a bit?